# How to send push notification with custom images to web application using FCM in java

Tags: firebase, spring-boot, firebase-cloud-messaging, spring-security-oauth2

I have created 2 simple applications; OAuth 2 spring boot based server app and a web based client app. After completing an activity, the server app is supposed to send a push notification to client app using FCM with some custom image.(images may vary depending on activity, like in Facebook ).

So can anyone tell me what is the best way to send custom images from server app to client app(web-based) using FCM? Give me just some basic hints

Although this can be done by first sending just urls of the custom images in notification, and then these urls will be used by client app to download images, but how to handle this if server is oauth protected(like in my case)? How it can be handled using server workers before showing a notification to user?

Is it good to first send an image from server side as Base-64 encoded string, and then decode this string back into an image on client-side?

Answer (score 0):

> So can anyone tell me what is the best way to send custom images from server app to client app(web-based) using FCM? Give me just some basic hints

For me, this `notification` worked (in PHP):

```
$notification = [
  'title' => 'Hello world',
  'body' => 'How are you?',
  'click_action' => 'https://www.example.com/app/#home',
  'icon' => 'https://www.example.com/icon.png'
];
```

This successfully delivers a Firebase Cloud Messaging push notification to a web application. If their browser is in the background, the `icon` will be displayed alongside the `title` and `body`, and then clicking on the notification will take them to the URL specified in the `click_action` property.

Knowing to use `icon` was the trickiest part for me, I was trying things like `image` and `picture`, but finally found some [docs about it here](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications).

> how to handle this if server is oauth protected(like in my case)? Is it good to first send an image from server side as Base-64 encoded string, and then decode this string back into an image on client-side?

I do not know the answer to these. Perhaps these questions should be asked in their own SA questions/threads. Good luck, and happy coding.